# Entity framework 4.1 tree mapping

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, mapping, entity-framework-4.1

I have problem with mapping classic db tree to entity framework entity.

Here is my db :

```
CREATE TABLE intranet_organization_units
(
 [OrganizationUnitId] INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
 [ParentOrganizationUnitId] INT NULL,
 [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
```

entity :

```
public class OrganizationUnit
{
    public int OrganizationUnitId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentOrganizationUnitId { get; set; }

    public virtual OrganizationUnit ParentOrganizationUnit { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrganizationUnit> ChildrenUnits { get; set; } 
}
```

and finally mapping :

```
   public class OrganizationUnitMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<OrganizationUnit>
    {
        public OrganizationUnitMapper()
        {
            ToTable("intranet_organization_units");
            Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("Name").IsRequired();


            HasMany(x => x.ChildrenUnits).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(x => x.OrganizationUnitId);
            HasOptional(x => x.ParentOrganizationUnit).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentOrganizationUnitId);

        }
    }
```

When I run application, I get this exception :

One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

> System.Data.Edm.EdmAssociationEnd: :
>   Multiplicity is not valid in Role
>   'OrganizationUnit_ChildrenUnits_Target'
>   in relationship
>   'OrganizationUnit_ChildrenUnits'.
>   Because the Dependent Role refers to
>   the key properties, the upper bound of
>   the multiplicity of the Dependent Role
>   must be �1�.

So where is problem? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
public class OrganizationUnitMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<OrganizationUnit>
{
    public OrganizationUnitMapper()
    {
        ToTable("intranet_organization_units");
        Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("Name").IsRequired();

        this.HasOptional(x => x.ParentOrganizationUnit)
            .WithMany(y => y.ChildrenUnits)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentOrganizationUnitId);
    }
}
```

When defining this association mapping you say:

- Organization unit has optional parent
- Parent can have multiple children
- And child use property for foreign key